# Can you post to Pub/Sub from BigQuery (maybe with a JS UDF)?

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, user-defined-functions

I'd really like to post from BigQuery SQL routines *into* Pub/Sub -- for example, to post a "Completed" message after a routine finishes, push out debug info, etc. Unfortunately, all the information I can find is about pushing data *from* Pub/Sub *into* BigQuery tables, which is the opposite of what I need.

I know there aren't any SQL commands to do that, but it seems to me that if you can write a JavaScript Cloud Function that posts to Pub/Sub (which you obviously can), then shouldn't you be able to write a persistent JS UDF that does the same thing?

(Unfortunately, I have decent Python skills, but no JavaScript...if BigQuery allowed Python UDFs, I could probably figure this out on my own.) TIA for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use eventarc triggers for this.

When a BigQuery job completes, a new entry is added into Cloud logging within your GCP project and this can be used to trigger a Cloud Run service.

The best is to refer to [this article](https://lakshmanok.medium.com/how-to-trigger-cloud-run-actions-on-bigquery-events-e818ee910560), which I find really good and adapt it to your needs.

And you can use Python!

Answer (score 2):

In addition of eventarc, you have 2 other solutions:

- You can use [Scheduled queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) on BigQuery if it's routine query. You can add a pubsub topic at the end of the scheduled query
- You can use [Workflow](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs). Create a step that calls BigQuery. When if is over, continue to the next step(s)